# Ajax.BeginForm - How to access new DOM objects from PartialView?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have following div, which is loading Partial View

```
<div id="_customerForm">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Customer/_customerForm.cshtml", Model.customerForm)
</div>
```

In that Partial View I have Ajax Form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateCustomer",
        "Customer",
         new AjaxOptions()
         {
               HttpMethod = "POST",
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               UpdateTargetId = "_customerForm",
         }
))
{
...
}
```

And When I submit the Ajax Form, the Partial View, including Ajax Form, is regenerated (by new model from server)

The problem I am facing is that I have jquery event attached to one of the input of that form, which works, until the form is refreshed. For example

```
$("#CustomerAddressList").change(function () { ... });
```

Change event on `#CustomerAddressList` DOM works until `#CustomerAddressList` is refreshed by new PartialView model, any idea ?

Comment: One option is to change your jQuery binding to something like `$("body").on("change", "#CustomerAddresslist", function() {});`. This causes the binding to pick up the change even if the element is deleted and recreated. You could also replace `"body"` with a more specific selector and parent of the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(document).on("change", "#CustomerAddressList", function(){
...
});
```

or

```
$("body").on("change", "#CustomerAddressList", function(){
...
});
```

Because the listener is bound to an element which is persistent on the page, it doesn't matter if the item which the selector references is dynamic content or not.

[.on documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: `document` does not work but `body` does, thank you!

Comment: Fixed, document doesn't require speech marks - glad to help, you can be more specific to improve performance, but body and document will always work